# Old issues of "C++ Report"?

Tags: c++

I used to receive  "C++ Report" magazine (along with "C/C++ User's Journal"), both now defunct.

For the longest time, I would cart around the issues, from move to move.  Regrettably, a few years ago I decided to stop carting them around & I recycled them.

There was a lot of wisdom in those pages, and now I find myself wishing I could bring them into the workplace so that others can peruse them.  A lot of what I know & use came from those pages.

**Does anyone know if back issues, or a DVD/CD-rom compilation of "C++ Report" exists?**

I know for example that **[Dr. Dobbs has a DVD](https://store.ddj.com/product/4/Dr.-Dobb%27s-Developer-Library-DVD-Release-5)** with 14 years of back issues of "C/C++ User's Journal".  I'd love to find something similar (or the dead tree equivalent) for "C++ Report".

(At the risk of sounding like a jerk, I'm not looking for a few articles by 1 or 2 authors from googling, I'm looking for the "whole shebang").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the book "C++ Gems", which is basically 42 articles from the first 7 years, published in 1996. I got a copy from a used bookstore a few years ago.

It would be nice to have a dvd - I have the Dr. Dobbs and C/C++ UJ ones. The indexing seems a little flakey, but everything is there if you look hard enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Funny you mention "C++ Gems" -- that's actually what got this whole thing started.  I was unpacking a box & came across my copy of that book... which immediately led to the sinking feeling when I remembered what I'd done with all the dead trees!

Comment: Looks like there is also a "More C++ Gems": http://www.amazon.com/More-Gems-SIGS-Reference-Library/dp/0521786185/ref=sr_1_sc_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1350235001&sr=8-2-spell&keywords=c%2B%2B+genms

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting the publisher.